# libvirt and usb passthrou without reset

Tags: usb, android, libvirt

I am trying to connect my android phone to a virtual windows machine.

The issue is that whenever I connect the phone it is in "charging" mode (this is an android security feature)
I then click on the phone to change it to "file transfer" mode. This momentarily disconnects the phone from the PC, while it changes mode. 
This breaks both USB passthrou (and redirect) and I have do "virsh attach-device"

When I do "virsh attach-device" (or do usb redirect in spice) the PC momentarily disconnects the phone putting it back in "charging" mode, before connecting it the to virtual machine.

This creates a circle, where I am unable to have a phone in "file transfer" mode accessible in a virtual machine.

Do you have any ideas or workarounds for this issue?

Comment: What happens if you put the phone in file-transfer mode *before* redirecting it?

Comment: Security on android does not permit that.

Comment: OK, I tested this and it worked. Mint 19.2 host, Fedora 31 guest. Plugged in the phone, changed to MTP (file transfer mode). Started the VM, then selected *Redirect USB* from the **virt-manager** menu (after logging in). The USB device showed up just fine. Now, I did not have the device mounted on the host before redirecting; not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: You are right, I now get the same result. I am now able to do usb redirect in MTP/"file transfer" mode. 
I must have had some sort of background doing strange things. Thanks for testing - it is much appreciated.